# Meteor: how to re-run a query from a helper with a html link tag?

Tags: meteor, hyperlink, parameters, helper

I have an html tag as follow:

```
<a id="random" href="/posts/rand">Randome Com</a>
```

which takes me to the following route: `http://localhost:3000/posts/rand`.

I have a view like this one:

```
        {{#each posts}}
            {{text}}
        {{/each}}
```

And when the params are posts/rand my helper "posts"return the following:

```
...
    else if (Session.get("order") == "rand") {
                    random = Math.random();
                    result = Posts.find({"random": {"$gt": random}}, {limit: 1})
                    if (result.fetch().length == 0) {
                        return Posts.find({"random": {"$lt": random}}, {limit: 1})
                    }else{
                        return result
                    };

                }
...
```

**Everything work fine however here's my question:**

When I click the link once it works but if re-click the link it will not work unless I manually refresh the browser? How can I define that after clicking the link it can be clicked again so that it return a new random post without having to refresh the browser ?

Comment: Is result actually changing each time you click the button? Console.log that out and see if it changes. If it does, this is a reactive issue.

Comment: result does not change each time I click the button. It only change id I refresh the browser or manually change the params back and forth. That is my problem I would like that it changes each time its clicked.

Answer (score 0):

I have the solution:

the problem was that when I clicked the link it would just change the params but if i decide to keep on clicking so that it displays new random posts it would not work. My solution was to add an event calling the `a` tag like this:

```
'click a#random': function() {
        if (Session.get("order") == "rand") {
            location.reload(true);
        };      
}
```

**note**: Make sure to check with an if statment that the page you want to reload is pointing at the current page you want to reload. This is important because `location.reload()`only reload the page it is at.

Now the page reload when its clicked. But a new problem occurred. Then new problem was that in my helpers the random post was retrieved too late after the page had reloaded so my solution was to remove the code that I had in my `else if` statement and place in a lib directory so that it become a global function that would be loaded first and then I can call it in my helper like bellow:

```
else if (Session.get("order") == "rand") {
                return Meteor.myFunctions.random_post()
                // random = Math.random();
                // result = Posts.find({"random": {"$gt": random}}, {limit: 1})
                // if (result.fetch().length == 0) {
                //  //console.log(result.fetch())
                //  return Posts.find({"random": {"$lt": random}}, {limit: 1})
                // }else{
                //  //console.log(result.fetch())
                //  return result
                // };
```

The commented part is what allowed me to build my global function `random_post()`